# "Вместе с тем(,) если..." Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Вместе с тем(,) если со стороны потребителя имело место злоупотребление правом, противоправное удаление с тепловой сети изолирующего материала, неправомерное отключение (демонтаж) энергопринимающего устройства, то он не может быть освобожден от оплаты тепловой энергии.**

Нужна ли запятая? Каким правилом регламентируется?

Comment: Нужно давать полностью предложение. Попробуйте вынуть придаточное "если со стороны....". Если легко вынимается, ставьте запятые перед союзом если и в конце придаточного, не вынимается - запятая перед если не нужна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вместе с тем, если со стороны потребителя имело место злоупотребление правом...**

Здесь желательно поставить запятую, так как наречие **вместе с тем** плохо согласуется с последующим текстом и поэтому требуется пауза при чтении

Сравнить: **Вместе с тем есл**и права его действИтельно были  нарушены, то...

**Пояснение**

1) ***Вместе с тем***  считается наречием,  а не вводным словом, поэтому в начале предложения оно не обособляется, что указывается во всех правилах.

2) Правда, наречия тоже иногда обособляются, да и значение у этого наречного выражения близко к тематике вводных слов. Например: **Вместе с тем, проведенные в 2007 году парламентские выборы показали**, что в стране существует совершенно иная расстановка политических сил.

3) В сочетании с союзом ЕСЛИ (***вместе с тем если***) наречие обособляется практически всегда (если судить по материалам Нацкорпуса), причем это касается и союза ЕСЛИ...ТО, когда перестановка придаточного невозможна, например:  http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%EC%E5%F1%F2%E5%20%F1%20%F2%E5%EC%20%E5%F1%EB%E8&p=0

**Вместе с тем, если** развивать дальше дискуссионную тему о сходстве Самойлова и Пушкина, то необходимо отметить еще одну общую черту... [Александр Городницкий (2001)]

4) Но варианты без обособления иногда тоже встречаются: **Вместе с тем если** малышей не пасти, а именно воспитывать, то они очень быстро и охотно научатся технике общения. **Вместе с тем если** под давлением ЕС и ООН  власти пойдут на децентрализацию страны,  то просто не останется другого выбора...

5) Из этого следует, что **решение неоднозначно и скорее зависит от структуры придаточного предложения**, а именно  от его распространенности и от расстановки логических ударений в нем.